# Issues with Git status, showing my whole root directory

Tags: git

Sorry for the dumb question but it's late and I need sleep.
When I run "git status", this is what I am getting

> On branch master
>       " Untracked files:
>       (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)"
>       -help/
>       -version/
>       .Trash/
>       .bash_history
>       .bash_profile
>       .bower/
>       .cache/
>       .codeintel/
>       .composer/
>       .config/
>       .dbshell
>       .dotfiles/
>       .dropbox/
>       .filezilla/
>       .fontconfig/
>       .fonts/
>       .gem/
>       .gitconfig
>       .gitignore_global
>       .gvimrc
>       .heroku/
>       .hgignore_global
>       .idlerc/
>       .irb-history
>       .jam/
>       .lesshst
>       .mongorc.js
>       .mysql_history
>       .neocon/
>       .netrc
>       .node-gyp/
>       .npm/
>       .oh-my-zsh/
>       .phpsh/
>       .profile
>       .putty/
>       .rnd
>       .rvm/
>       .rvmrc
>       .sh_history
>       .ssh/
>       .subversion/
>       .swp
>       .vim.20121218/
>       .vim.20121230/
>       .vim/
>       .viminfo
>       .vimrc
>       .vimrc.20121218
>       .vimrc.after
>       .vimrc.before
>       .vimrc.bundles.fork
>       .vimrc.fork
>       .vimundo/
>       .vimviews/
>       .yeoman/
>       .zcompdump
>       .zlogin
>       .zprofile
>       .zsh-update
>       .zsh_history
>       .zshrc
>       Calibre Library/
>       Desktop/
>       Documents/
>       Downloads/
>       Dropbox/
>       FRONEND_MASTERS/
>       Happy.js/
>       JSON-js/
>       Learn-to-Program-Javascript/
>       Library/
>       Local_Test/
>       Moo3D/
>       Music/
>       My-sinatra-app-1/
>       MyBooks/
>       Nettuts-Builder.zip
>       PSD_Themes.zip
>       PSD_Themes/
>       Pictures/
>       Public/
>       SPA/
>       SilkJS-Harmony/
>       Sinatra-app-1/
>       Sites/24/
>       Sites/30days_revisited/
>       Sites/Ajax_Site/
>       Sites/Backbonejs-PHP/
>       Sites/Bat-Tracer/
>       Sites/DjangoBoss/
>       Sites/FsWebSpa-Backbone/
>       Sites/JS-Playground-Backbone/
>
> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Basically my whole ~ directory.
It's been a while since I messed around with GIT, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably did a `git init` in `~` at some point, probably by accident. Now you're in a subdirectory which doesn't have a close git repo, so you're seeing the result of `git` traversing up to your home directory.

Check your `git log` while in `~`. If there's no important changes, you can safely delete `~/.git` to get rid of the repo.

Comment: I'm a little wary to give that advice in case there are also useful accidental commits. Updated the answer.

Comment: I am trying it with rm -r .git

Comment: and it's not liking it. override r--r--r-- anthonybrown/staff for .git/objects/00/00cec00 and a whole bunch of numbers, what do I do now?

Comment: yes, that would work, but did you check for important changes? (Ah well, they're lost now in any case)

Comment: Some files are read-only...use `rm -rf` if you really want to nuke it all.

Comment: yes nothing important, when I run git status now it says "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: yes...that's kind of what it should say. You need to be in a directory with an actual repository. (If you just nuked an actual repository, don't say I didn't warn you)

Comment: I am trying to upgrade oh-my-zsh, when I run the command it still says "You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).  Please, commit your changes before you can merge. I don't understand what that means?

Comment: OK, you should probably just learn `git` before you make a serious mistake...or get some sleep. (I am becoming increasingly afraid that I'm going to be responsible for you carelessly nuking something critical here)

Comment: okay lol thanks for your concern, you are probably right, although I cd into oh-my-zsh and ran git status and it returned # On branch master  nothing to commit (working directory clean)